# How to only bundle files in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

So for various reasons I have a need to bundle React.

So in the bundleconfig.json I set it up as so

```json
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/app.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/libs/React/react-17-0-2.js",
      "Scripts/dist/index.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": false,
      "renameLocals": false
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  }
```

But no matter what I have tried the React is minified.

I gave up and used the files separately, but I would love to know how you can only bundle the files and not minify them.